# How to use rating for SharePoint List in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, rating

I'm trying to get the SharePoint Ratings feature to work with PowerApp's Ratings control; there's no obvious way to correctly bind the two.

### Detail

SharePoint lists have a [Star Ratings](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-a-ratings-feature-to-your-library-5901fcfd-19ca-4f27-a65f-284654298552) feature which allows users to rate any item in a list, and provides an average rating for that item.

PowerApps has a Rating control which allows you to use star ratings systems / there's a tutorial on using this [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-bind-powerapps-rating-control-to-sharepoint-column2/).  However the tutorial shows how to associate a numeric field in SharePoint with the ratings control in PowerApps. 
 I'm after using the Rating control in PowerApps with the Rating feature in SharePoint.

- I want the ability to get/set the rating given by the current user; so they can submit & amend their score for the system.
- I also want to be able to provide the aggregate rating for this item given all users inputs.

When I deal with the SP Rating field in PowerApps I seem to get a text response; giving a comma separated list of ratings.  Is there any way for me to get this as an array of numbers I can pass to the `Average` function?

Also is there a way I can hook into the current user's rating, such that they can submit a new rating and have their previous rating removed / replaced?

Comment: (followup question for allowing users to manage their own rating here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/280645/update-a-sharepoint-rating-column-through-powerapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Average and CountIf function in PoweApps:

https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2019/10/30/how-to-get-the-ratings-from-sharepoint-into-your-powerapp/

```
If(
    IsBlank(
        Average(
            TrimEnds(
                Split(
                    ThisItem.'User ratings'
                    ,
                    ","
                )
            ).Result
            , 
            Result
        )
    )
    ,
    "0"
    ,
    Average(
        TrimEnds(
            Split(
                ThisItem.'User ratings'
                ,
                ","
            )
        ).Result
        ,
        Result
    )
)
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-rating#related-functions

Comment: Ah nice; thank-you; it was the use of "Result" that I was missing / I'd just assumed the output of one function could go directly into the other, rather than suspecting it would create a Result column in the background. `If (IsBlank(ThisItem.'User ratings'),"Not Rated",Left("★★★★★",Round(Average(TrimEnds(Split(ThisItem.'User ratings',",")).Result, Value(Result)),0)))` (I ended up using a text field instead of Ratings field as wanted to include the result in a DataTable / couldn't nest the Rating control in the cell).

Comment: ps. Any idea on how to do the second part of my question; i.e. allow a user to update their rating (given the value returned seems to be an anonymous csv of all ratings)?  If not I'll post that as a separate question.  Thank-you again.

Comment: ThisItem.'User ratings' isn't recognized for some reason. I have the star ratings on and everything too